Permission denied for tablespace while creating a VIEW in Postgres
During a run of my synchronising script for a postrgresdb, I run into an error, and I have no idea how to solve this:
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [create or replace view applicatiepakket_instelling_klas_detail_vw",
    
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW app_institution_class_detail_vw AS
WITH class_detail AS (
    SELECT 
        instnumber,
        classnumber,
        MIN(type) AS type,
        MIN(code) AS code,
        COUNT(1) AS numberids
    FROM 
        class_desc ki1
    GROUP BY 
        instnumber, classnumber
)
SELECT 
    aic.id AS id,
    ai.id AS app_institution_id,
    cd.classnumber,
    cd.type,
    cd.code,
    cd.numberids,
    (aic.id IS NOT NULL) AS active
FROM 
    class_detail cd
INNER JOIN 
    app_institution ai ON ai.instnumber = cd.instnumber
LEFT JOIN 
    app_institution_class aic ON (aic.app_institution_id = ai.id AND aic.classnumber = cd.classnumber);

     nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for tablespace ilo",
"\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:99)",
|                "\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)",
|                "\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)",
|                "\tat org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)",
|                "\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:416)",
|                "\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:549)",

I am trying to create a view in the database, but I run into a permission denied error. What could be the problem.
The tables in the view exist, and I assume the permissions are set correctly; otherwise, they wouldn't be created.

why did you delete the error it is vital to the question

you  should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71231494/postgresql-create-view-and-use-of-default-tablespace

It doesn't work, when i execute the script of that question, i get the same error : permission denied

So You must grant as superuser the user who tries to create the view the rights

Isn't there a way to force the script to use a different tablespace, in which my user has rights?

Not that is mentioned in the manual it would always use the default or connected tablespace
